# Find with permission and group

Tags: find

How can i find files with write permission for the group "others", regardless of any other permissions, with extension ".sh" (use symbolic format)

I've already tried

```
find / -type f -perm -g=w -name "*.sh"
```

Comment: Please edit question to clarify (don't leave comments). When done delete your comment.

Comment: Please also [edit] and tell us what operating system you are using. There are many different `find` implementations, so knowing the OS can help us know which one you are using and what options you have available.

Comment: @terdon srry done

Comment: Are you really using Unix? Which one? Are you sure you're not using some form of Linux instead? What happens when you run the command you tried? Do you get any errors? Does it get no results? Wrong results?

Comment: @terdon its a question for  homework :') it just says that it's a Unix or Unix-like system

Comment: Do you knew what Unix you are using (not in the question) is it UNIX (which one), BSD (Which one), Gnu/Linux (which one)?

Comment: Are you referring to an actual group called `others`, or to the third set of permission bits?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find all regular files in or below the current directory that are writable by "others" (i.e. that someone has done `chmod o+w` on):

```
find . -type f -perm -o=w
```

Leaving the `-` off from `-o=w` would test if the permissions on the file was exactly `o=w` (i.e. not anything else than writable for "others").

Answer (score 0):

Is this helps :

```
find ./ -perm /g+w -type f -name "*.sh" -exec ls -l {} \;
```